# Docker jmeter instances on multiple AWS instances/machines

Tags: jmeter

We are using Docker jmeter containers for jmeter distributed testing, able to run from one AWS instance (one master and 3 slaves in the same instance/VM) and getting results in results.csv file. Would like to know if there is any way to configure some more slaves in another AWS instance/VM. Basically two VMs should be used for load distribution testing. One VM with master running and some slaves with another VM only to run slave. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you know you have to publish client/server RMI ports in docker (since you've already manage to run it on one host).

Then the next thing to mind is that RMI needs all parties to be in one physical subnet.

As soon as you can't really guarantee it at AWS, suggestion here is to establish the SSH tunneling (port forwarding) between AWS instance running JMeter master & the instance(s) running slave containers.

[Here's](http://www.testingdiaries.com/jmeter-on-aws/) pretty good guideline for that (not mine :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for sharing info. Able to accomplish the task by following below article. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-using-docker-in-aws/#comment-3265

Answer (score 0):

Able to accomplish the task by following below article steps. With two EC2 instances, one acting as master and other one as slave, able to run test scripts in master.
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-using-docker-in-aws/#comment-3265